# How to get a script triggered by a rule to run as a certain user

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a script which runs when a new item appears in a folder; the items in the folder come from the inbound email alias. When I add content to the folder the rule fires correctly, however when it runs as a result of the email arriving I get an error "You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation"

Is it possible to get this script to run as a user who does have permission on the folder?

Comment: Are you happy to write a few lines of Java? Or does it have to be a pure-JS solution?

Comment: I'm not unhappy with Java, but it's an extra deployment method requiring a restart of the server. I'd be happiest if I could do it by pushing a script into the Data Dictionary. That said, if you have an answer that requires Java, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some Java, then you'd want to use something like [AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/datamodel/org/alfresco/repo/security/authentication/AuthenticationUtil.html#runAsSystem%28org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork%29) to have your code run as the system, which is allowed to write to everything.

If you want to keep most things in JavaScript, then write a [Custom Action](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Actions) in Java that does the runAsSystem, then within that have it call the ScriptService to execute your JavaScript.

Normally, one might suggest that you configure your custom action to accept as a parameter the script to run. However, given that it'll run the script with full privs, that's not so wise, so instead maybe hard code it, and take care that you don't expose something that lets users do naughty things as system!